# Can I sacrifice the old and weak, or is a graveyard necessary in Black and White?

Tags: black-and-white

In Black and White, I've always heard that graveyards are necessary so [villagers don't waste too much time mourning the dead](http://www.rdrop.com/~half/General/GameTips/bw.tips.html#weather). Advice I've newly read suggests, however, that building a graveyard is a waste of time and [the old, the dead, even children](http://www.wischik.com/lu/senses/bwhints.html#worshippers) can be sacrificed with great benefit.

I've always thought that it hurt my society to sacrifice villagers, and settled for giving food instead. If I consistently sacrifice the weak and dead, however, can I save resources and do without a graveyard as well? Or, will my villagers still notice and mourn?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Villagers mourn only when there are skeletal remains left. Since sacrificing old villagers won't leave any they won't mourn, but it makes you more evil.

Comment: so does picking up the remains, although I think it's slightly less evil...